# Django forms's logic for a form in a base template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with this situation. I have three views:

```
def view0(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def view1(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

Both view templates extends a template called 'base.html', in which there is a contact form.

What I'm wondering is: do I need to write python code in both views to handle all the logic inherent in the form's operation? Or can I create a view whose only job is to handle the logic of this specific form?

I tried to create a separate view, assigning it a url to which the 'action' attribute of the form refers:

```
def base_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        contact_form = Form(request.POST)
        #logic here
    else:
        contact_form = Form()
    context = {'contact_form': contact_form}
    return render (request, 'base.html', context)

def view0(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def view1(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

'base.html' has the following code for the form:

```
.....

<form action="{% url 'base_view_url' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{contact_form}}
   <input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>

.....
```

With this code the contact form does not work.

Comment: So where is `base_view_url` linked to the `base_view` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back a bit to the basics to understand how forms work.

1. Each form has an action URL, which will be called once the form is submitted.
2. Once the user submits the form, the browser will encode the form data and send it to action URL.
3. Once the action URL is received by Django, it will match the URL against the URL patterns to decide which view to call.
4. The view will process the data and return a response to the user.

So to answer your question.
You need only one view to handle the form (given that the form is the same in both views) and you can set the action URL to always call 'base_view_url'.
Also, the page can have multiple forms, each with different action URL.